# MVC DropDownList lagging

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am posting the id of a dropdownlist back to the index (index2 view).  but is lagging behind.  After a second time pressing Select it shows me the correct list.

http://www.jeroenchristens.be/CountriesWorld
(the first page is only for showing the complete list, after selecting from the dropdownlist,, it gets to index2, a shorter list)  And then after choosing another Selection from the dropdownlist, you have to try this twice each time.

I successfully copied this from the id the value and pass this on, why is it lagging behind.

Index2 Viewpage

```
@using System.Collections
@using System.Web.UI.WebControls
@model IEnumerable<CVtje.Models.Countries>


<h2>Index</h2>
@using (Html.BeginForm("Index2", "CountriesWorld", new { @id = Request.Form["SelectedContinent"] }, FormMethod.Post))
{
    <div class="form-group">

        @Html.DropDownList("SelectedContinent", 
            new SelectList((IEnumerable) ViewData["continentsList"], "Continent", "Continentomschrijving"))
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Select</button>
    </div>
}
    <table id="countriesworld" class="table table-active table-hover">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Vlag</th>
                <th>
                    Code
                </th>
                <th>
                    Land
                </th>
                <th>Continent</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <img src="@string.Format("../../images/countries/{0}.png", item.Code)" width="25" HEIGHT="15" />

                </td>
                <td>

                    @item.Code



                </td>


                <td>
                    @item.Country
                    @*@Html.ActionLink("Details", "Index", "ReizensDetails", new { id = item.ReizenId }, null)*@


                    @*|
                        @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id = item.Id }) |
                        <button data-myprofile-id="@item.Id" class="btn-link js-delete">Delete</button>*@
                </td>
                <td>@item.Continents.Continentomschrijving</td>
            </tr>
        }

    </table>
```

**my controller:**

```
public ActionResult Index(int? id)
{


    List<Continents> continentsList = new List<Continents>();
    continentsList = _context.Continents.ToList();
    ViewData["continentsList"] = continentsList;

    var countriesWorld = _context.Countries.OrderBy(e => e.Country).ToList();

    return View(countriesWorld);

}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index2(int id)
{

    //return View(db.MyProfiles.ToList());
    List<Continents> continentsList = new List<Continents>();
    continentsList = _context.Continents.ToList();
    ViewData["SelectedContinent"] = id.ToString();
    ViewData["continentsList"] = continentsList;



        var countriesWorld = _context.Countries.Where(e => e.Continent == id).OrderBy(e => e.Country).ToList();

    return View(countriesWorld);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have added a route value using `new { @id = Request.Form["SelectedContinent"] }` in your `BeginForm()` method.

Assuming the initial value is `0`, then it generates `action = "/CountriesWorld/Index2/0"`. Lets assume you select the option with `value="1"` and you now post the form. The `id` attribute is bound to `0` and you filter the Countries based on `.Where(e => e.Continent == 0)` - no where have you ever used the value of the selected option which is bound to a non-existent property named `SelectedContinent`.

Now you return the view and the forms `action` attribute is now `action = "/CountriesWorld/Index2/1"` (because `Request.Form["SelectedContinent"]` is `1`). If you select the option with `value="2"`, the same thing occurs - you ignore the value of the selected option and the filter the Countries based on `.Where(e => e.Continent == 1)` because the `id` parameter is `1`.

Always bind to a model, which in your case will be

```
public class CountriesVM
{
    public int? SelectedContinent { get; set }
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> ContinentsList { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Country> Countries { get; set; }
}
```

and in the view, strongly bind to your model (note the `FormMethod.Get` and the 3rd parameter in `DropDownListFor()`)

```
@model CountriesVM
@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "CountriesWorld", FormMethod.Get))
{
    @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SelectedContinent, Model.ContinentsList, "All")
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Select</button>
}
<table ... >
    ....
    @foreach(var country in Model.Countries)
    {
        ....
    }
 </table>
```

and you need only one method

```
public ActionResult Index(int? selectedContinent)
{
    var countries = _context.Countries.OrderBy(e => e.Country);
    if (selectedContinent.HasValue)
    {
        countries = countries.Where(e => e.Continent == selectedContinent.Value);
    }
    continentsList = _context.Continents.Select(x => new SelectListItem
    {
        Value = x.Continent.ToString(),
        Text = x.Continentomschrijving
    });
    var model = new CountriesVM
    {
        SelectedContinent = selectedContinent,
        ContinentsList = continentsList,
        Countries = countries
    };
    return View(model);
}
```

Note you might also want to consider caching the `Continents` to avoid repeated database calls assuming they do not change often (and invalidate the cache if their values are updated)

Comment: I counted them too like this, and indeed I know about models like these ones, but I thought they only applied to bigger models with lots of dropdownlists.

Comment: it is working fine.  So if I add other controls like a checkbox, (to be able to select on with the query), I do also need to add this to the ViewModel: this means: adding a List/var and a selectedVar.  Ok, this is no problem, I understand the principle, the other things are working fine.

Comment: I got it working with two Dropdownlists (an extra one for choosing the language) and also added these to the viewmodel (http://www.jeroenchristens.be/CountriesWorld)

Comment: Good for you :)

Comment: just another thing, why can't I search for one particular country.  if I used the 3rd dropdowlist op top of the page to select a country.  And than I would like to search for that same Country in the table, that won't work (that one country is also in the list), check it here: http://www.jeroenchristens.be/CountriesWorld/Compare

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you mean. I'm not sure what that 3rd dropdownlist is for or what the issue is, and I don't know what your code for it is

Comment: no problem, but if you select a particular country with the dropdownlist, than you can't search for that particular country in the table.

Comment: I assume that would be because you have not written the code for that correctly (but I do not know what your code is). I suggest you ask a new question explaining the issue and the code you have tried

Comment: ok, no problem, no both  the codes are within the same form, but they work fine seperately, it's only in this rare case.  I will debug it later.