# ViewModel to display dropdownlist not working

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-5

I am learning ASP.NET MVC on my own and building a sample web app that I learned from video tutorials and reading books.

I am building an web app using code first with existing database. Everything was working well when I was working with viewbags. When I tried to change viewbags to viewmodel, my code start breaking.

My model looks like:

```
public partial class APPET1
{
    [Column("Doc Number")]
    [StringLength(255)]
    public string Doc_Number { get; set; }
    [StringLength(255)]
    public string CCode { get; set; }
    public DateTime? Date { get; set; }
    [StringLength(255)]
    public string Remark { get; set; }
    public int? StatusID { get; set; }
    public virtual Status Status { get; set; }
}
```

This is my view:

```
<table>
<tr>
  @using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "APPET1", FormMethod.Get))
  {
  
    <td>
<tr>
    <td width="200px"> <label>Search Everything </label></td>
    <td> @Html.TextBox("Search", null)</td>


    <td width="200px"><label>Search Document Number Only </label></td>
    <td>@Html.TextBox("DocNumber", null)</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td width="200px"><label>Remark Contains </label></td>
    <td>@Html.TextBox("Remark", null)</td>

    <td>Status</td>
    <td>@Html.DropDownListFor(t=>t.Status, Model.Statuses, "Select Status")</td>
</tr>
          
    </td>
         <tr>
             <td><button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" style="font-weight:bold">Search</button></td>
    ..........some more codes .............
                
          }
          
        </tr>
    </table>
```

IndexAction method in my controller looks like:

```
public class APPET1Controller : Controller
{
    private APContext db = new APContext();

    // GET: APPET1
    public ActionResult Index(string search, string cagecode, string sortBy, int? page, string docNumber, string remark, string status)
    {
        APPETViewModel viewModel = new APPETViewModel();

        var aPPET1 = db.APPET1.Include(t =>T.APPETMedia)
                                    .Include(t => t.Status)
                                    .Include(t => t.APPETCCode)
                                    .Include(t => t.APPETDType);
                                    
        
        DateTime searchDate;
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(search))
        {
            bool isDateSearch = DateTime.TryParse(search, out searchDate);
            if (isDateSearch)
            {
                aPPET1 = aPPET1.Where(s => s.Date_Received == searchDate);
            }
      
            else
            {
                aPPET1 = aPPET1.Where(t.Doc_Number.Contains(search)
                        || t.Status.Status1.Contains(search)
                        || t.Remark.Contains(search)
                        || t.CCode.Contains(search));
            //ViewBag.Search = search;
               viewModel.Search = search;
            }

        }
        var statuses = db.APPETS.Select(t => t.Status.Status1);
        
        if(!String.IsNullOrEmpty(status))
        {
           aPPET1 = aPPET1.Where(t => t.Status.Status1.Contains(status));

        }
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(docNumber))
        {   
            aPPET1 = aPPET1.Where(t => t.Doc_Number.Contains(docNumber));
        }
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(remark))
        {
            aPPET1 = aPPET1.Where(t => t.Remark.Contains(remark));
        }
 ............some more codes.........
        return View(viewModel);
      
    }
```

In my ViewModel I added:

```
    public string Status { get; set;} 
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Statuses { get; set; }
```

I know I am missing something, but couldn't figure out what. I read many stackoverflow posts and now I am upto that point where you look at a word for so long and its spelling start looking weird. Based on the posts and article I read I am either getting

> Value cannot be null. Parameter Name:items

error or

> There is no ViewData item of type 'IEnumerable

error. Can anyone of you expert point me what I need to fix to get my dropdownlist working. Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: Where have you set the value of `Model.Statuses`? (its `null`, hence the error)

Comment: You need to set `viewModel.Statuses` property to a list of `SelectListItem` in your GET action (Generate that from the Status collection).

Comment: Refer the controller code in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49731441/mvc-dropdownlist-lagging/49732337#49732337) for how you should be setting it

Comment: @Stephen, thank you for your help. I was also reading your post from 2016 which helped as well. I set the value for my viewModel.Statuses and it start working fine.

Comment: @Shyju, thank you too.

Comment: Answers do not go in the question (I have rolled back your changes)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my get action method, I edited the following codes

```
var statuses = db.APPETS.Select(t => t.Status.Status1);

    if(!String.IsNullOrEmpty(status))
    {
       aPPET1 = aPPET1.Where(t => t.Status.Status1.Contains(status));

    }
```

to

```
var stats = db.Status.Select(s => s.Status1);
viewModel.Statuses = new SelectList(stats);
  {

     if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(status))
        {
           aPPET1 = aPPET1.Where(t => t.Status.Status1.Contains(status));

        }
  }
```

and my app started working as expected. @Stephen thank you for you prompt response and help.