# Search using dropdown list not working

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Refering to the [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49742149/viewmodel-to-display-dropdownlist-not-working) I have asked few weeks ago, I have a new issue now. I have added few more dropdownlist and have been able to get all of them working but while searching one of it doesn't work. Below is the one that is not working. My dropdownlist is populated but while searching I don't get any results but in url it shows that list item I have picked.

In my model class I added

```
public int? SectionID {get; set;}
public virtual Section Section {get; set;}
```

In my viewmodel class I added

```
public string SecClass{get; set;}
public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> secclasses {get; set;}
```

My view looks like

```
<td> <label class="col-form-label col-form-label-lg" for="inputLarge"> Section </label> </td>
<td> @Html.DropDownListFor(s => s.SecClass, Model.secclasses, "", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control", @id = "exampleSelect1" })</td>
```

And here is my controller

```
var sec = db.Section.Select(s => s.Section1);
viewModel.secclasses = new SelectList(sec);

if(!String.IsNullOrEmpty(section))
{
    aPPET1 = aPPET1.Where(s => s.Section.Section1.Contains(section));
}
```

When I debug, "sec" will give me the list as desired. But "section" is showing up as null.

From last two days I have been trying to figure out but no success yet. Can you point me where am I making mistake please?

Comment: How does your HttpPost action method signature looks like ?

Comment: @Shyju, I thought I only need one method. In my previous question Stephen Muecke pointed out to this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49731441/mvc-dropdownlist-lagging/49732337#49732337)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After burning my brain all weekend, this morning I finally got it to work. All I did was change

```
var sec = db.Section.Select(s => s.Section1);
```

"sec" to "SecClass" same as in my viewmodel which is

```
public string SecClass{get; set;}
```

Comment: My application is working as I wanted it to, but I still don't understand why those two names need to be same. I also tried and change the name to all lower case and it still works. So, I believe for some reason only names should be similar.